# Завершение docker-compose с ошибкой

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jenkins, test-automation, makefile

Пускаю в докере тесты. Описываю пайплайн.

У меня есть 2 композа. В одном из них пускаются сервисы (full.yml). В другом -- тесты (test-runner.yml). В докерфайлах используются make-файлы, чтобы унифицировать интерфейс доступа к запуску программ и сервисов. Поступаю так:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.full.yml up -d
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up
docker-compose -f docker-compose.full.yml down
```

Но если сервисы не поднялись, либо не удалось достучаться до базы, то докер-композ завершается без кода ошибки и, соответственно, это нехорошо, так как в jenkins я не могу уронить пайплайн. Как сделать так, чтобы докер-композ test.yml завершался с ошибкой в любом случае, кроме валидного прохождения тестов?

Answer (score 0):

Если я верно понял, то проблема в том, что во второй команде есть некий "главный" контейнер, ошибка которого глотается композом.

Наверное следует эту команду разбить на две:
1. `docker-compose up`, убрав из test "главный" образ
2. `docker run -it <"главный" образ> ...`
Тогда вторая команда по идее вернет ошибку, если что.